# Regular parse pattern for exclusion of match

Tags: python, regex

How can I retrieve only `NP`:

```
ROOT -> NP
```

More general `string1 -> string2` 
I need to extract `string2`

Comment: Can you describe in words what you expect this regex to do, in the general case?

Comment: To get `NP` here, you do not need a regex, something like `s[s.find(" -> ") + 4:]` will do. Or `s.split(" -> ")[1]`. See the [demo](https://ideone.com/gmHncw).

Comment: I get nothing, i am checking in http://regexpal.com/.

Comment: more general would be `word1 -> word2` . I need to extract `word2`.

Comment: Why are you using square brackets? I'm no regexpert but it looks like the first group in your regex is actually matching "one character that is not a parenthesis, whitespace, asterisk, or any character with code between boundary and the greater than symbol". The second group just consumes whitespace. So you're just getting a single character followed by whitespace.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just out the pattern after `->` within a capture group.
Also don't forgot to add a white space before your pattern:

```
->\s(\w+)
```

See demo : https://regex101.com/r/lP0lT3/1

---

You can use `re.search` to capture the first group :

```
print(re.search(r'->\s(\w+)', my_string).group(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

`\b` is for *boundary*, not for *blank*. To match spaces you must use `\s`.

Here, the regex representing *a word, optional spaces, '->', optional spaces, a word* would be: `\w+\s*->\s*\w+`.

If you want to just capture second word, and add provision for optional initial spaces, you could use:

```
m = re.match('\s*\w+\s*->\s*(\w+)', 'ROOT -> NP')
print(m.group(1))
```

gives `NP`